# Finding effective annual rate of interest

Tags: finance

The present value of $2x$ paid at the end of $k$ years and the present value of  $x$ paid at the end of $2k$ years sum up to $2x$. Show that the annual rate of interest is $(\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2})-1$

I tried summing the present values of each case.

Let $i$ be the annual effective rate of interest.

$$\begin{align}
2x(1+i)^k +x(1+i)^{2k} & =2x\\
2(1+i)^k+(i+i)^{2k} & =2 \\
\end{align}$$

Let $(1+i)^k=a$

$2a+a^2-2=0$

Using the quadratic formulae, I get $a=-1+\sqrt{3}$

Then I get $i=(-1+\sqrt{3})^{\frac{1}{k}}-1$.

But that is not the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in the solution. First of all the present value of $2x$ paid in $k$ years is $\frac{2x}{(1+i)^k}$. And the present value of $x$ paid in $2k$ years is $\frac{x}{(1+i)^{2k}}$. Therefore the equation is

$\frac{2x}{(1+i)^k}+\frac{x}{(1+i)^{2k}}=2x$

Let $\frac{1}{(1+i)^k}=z$

The equation becomes $2z+z^2=2$.

You will see that the solution is $i=\left(\frac{\sqrt 3+1}{2} \right)^{1/k}-1$.

Comment: Solving for $z=\frac{-2±\sqrt{4-4(1)(-2)}}{2}$=$-1±\sqrt{3}$. How come you arrive at this solution.

Comment: Here it is. Sorry 4 the inconvenience.

Comment: Right. $\sqrt 3-1=\left( \frac{1}{(1+i)}\right) ^k$ Go ahead.

Comment: Good. I got it. I missed the typo of present value. Thanks for taking time to explain

Comment: Nice that you get it. Your are welcome.